# GraphQL- conditionally determine the type of a field in a schema

Tags: graphql

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        account:{
           type:String,
           enum:['employee','admin'],
        },
    id: String,
    }
//other fields
})
```

Then in my `graphql-schemas` file, I have the following schema types:

```
const MessageType = new GraphQLObjectType({
     name: 'Message',
     fields: () => ({
        account: {
           type: AuthorType,
        //resolve method 
        },
        id: {type: GraphQLString},
   })
})

const AuthorType= new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'Author',
   fields: () => ({
     account: {
        type://This will either be AdminType or EmployeeType depending on the value of account in db (employee or admin),
        //resolve method code goes here
        }
})
```

})

As indicated in the comments of `AuthorType`, I need the `account` field to resolve to `Admin` or `Employee` depending on the value of the `account` field in the database. 
How do I conditionally determine the type of a field in a schema on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of determining the type on the fly, I restructured my code as shown below:

```
const MessageType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Message',
    fields: () => ({
       id:{type:GraphQLString},
        author: {
          type: AuthorType,
          async resolve(parent, args) {
            if (parent.author.account === 'guard') {
                return await queries.findEmployeeByEmployeeId(parent.author.id).then(guard => {
                    return {
                        username: `${guard.first_name} ${guard.last_name}`,
                        profile_picture: guard.profile_picture
                    }
                })
            } else if (parent.author.account === 'admin') {
                return {
                    username: 'Administrator',
                    profile_picture: 'default.jpg'
                }
            }
        }
    },
//other fields
   })
})

const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Author',
    fields: () => ({
       username: {type: GraphQLString},
       profile_picture: {type: GraphQLString},
  })
 })
```

Since all I need from the `AuthorType` is the author's username and profile picture, both employee and administrator have these fields, which I pass to `AuthorType`.
In `MessageType`, I apply the logic to determine account type in the `resolve` method of `author`, then construct custom object out of the logic, to match `AuthorType`.